# ws2812b + ESP32 + 2 meter wires

Tags: wiring, esp32, ws2812b

I have a WS2812B Led strip, and use a ESP32 with FastLED.

It works great, as long as the led strip is near the ESP32. as soon as I add a 2 meter extension cable between the esp and the leds it stops working. I tried to add a resistor on the data line as suggested on various sources on the web, but it did not get better. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Any sugestion is very welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Well other than "it does not work", we don't know what the problem even is. You need to show schematics and wiring. And measurements. For example you might have forgotten to level shift the 3.3V output to a 5V output which the LED requires.

Comment: @Justme, thanks for the input. I did not level shift the output as the schematics i found when I started the project did not require it. I tried to use a single led near the board, as a quick and dirty level shifterer, and then adding the 2 meters of wire and that did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addressable LEDs are powered with 5V supply and need 5V data input by specification, and it should not work with 3.3V MCU output at all.

Even if someone else says it works without level shifting, that is pure luck and affected by actual supply voltage and manufacturing tolerances as 3.3V may barely be recognizable as high by the 5V data input.

It may simply work because wire is just the right length to get overshoots on data line which may get recognized as high level.

Comment: thank you very much. thsi was indeed the problem.